# Logged into Facebook app on two phones

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, facebook

I received a Facebook message on my phone B, but cleared the notification. I deleted the Facebook message on phone B. Will phone A still receive the notification even though I cleared everything quickly?

Answer (score 1):

You will receive the notification on all devices that have a connection and have notifications for Facebook enabled, regardless of whether you have since cleared the notification on another device.